# Links in menu with domain name

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

When I create a link in a menu containing `localhost` it doesn't naturally work from outside. When I create a link with my public IP address it doesn't work from inside. Can I use some Drupal variables for this purpose containing the site name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just trying to create links to pages within your Drupal site you can use relative paths and when Drupal renders the link it will show as a complete URL.  You only need to have the domain name in the path when you are linking to an external site (not the same domain)

Example, to link to the Site Configuration admin page:

Use `admin/settings` instead of `http://localhost/admin/settings` and it will still show up in your menu as a full URL.

Comment: I can't do this. I have in the path `localhost/?q=something` if I replace it with `?q=something` it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't type in `?q=something` for the path, instead simply use `something` and Drupal will add the `?q=` later

Answer (score 0):

Enable clean URLs in apache configuration first (mod_rewrite) , then you will able to omit /q?= and hence can use admin/setting like URLS without the need of specifying domain name